# Rendering SLS 'base:docker.manager.first' failed: Jinja variable list object has no element 0

Tags: docker, jinja2, docker-swarm, salt-stack

Hello I have been trying to setup a Docker Swarm with Salt but I am sort of stuck...

I am getting the following error on applying:

```
Data failed to compile:
              ----------
                  Rendering SLS 'base:docker.manager.first' failed: Jinja variable list object has no element 0
```

This is my first.sls:

```
{% set manager_ip = salt['mine.get']('*', 'manager_ip').items()[0][1][0] %}

include:
  - docker.base

init new swarm cluster:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'docker swarm init --advertise-addr {{ manager_ip }}'
    - require:
      - pkg: docker-ce
```

This is my /srv/pillar/swarm.sls that provides the mine_functions:

```
mine_functions:
  network.ip_addrs: [ens32]
  manager_token:
    - mine_function: cmd.run
    - "docker swarm join-token manager -q"
  manager_ip:
    - mine_function: network.ip_addrs
    - ens32
  worker_token:
    - mine_function: cmd.run
    - "docker swarm join-token worker -q"
```

When running salt '*' pillar.items:

```
----------
mine_functions:
    ----------
    manager_ip:
        |_
          ----------
          mine_function:
              network.ip_addrs
        - ens32
    manager_token:
        |_
          ----------
          mine_function:
              cmd.run
        - docker swarm join-token manager -q
    network.ip_addrs:
        - ens32
    worker_token:
        |_
          ----------
          mine_function:
              cmd.run
        - docker swarm join-token worker -q
```

How do I fix this or is there any known way to setup a Docker Swarm using Salt?

Comment: Maybe try logging `manager_ip` using `{% salt.log_message(manager_ip) %}` (and removing the `[0][1][0]` to see what it really contains.

Comment: @match I did as you said and got the following error: [ERROR   ] {u'ret': {u'master.maf.cloud': [u"Rendering SLS 'base:docker.manager.first' failed: Jinja syntax error: Encountered unknown tag 'salt'.; line 1\n\n---\n{% salt.log_message(manager_ip) %}    <======================\n#{% set manager_ip = salt['mine.get']('*', 'manager_ip').items()[0][1][0] %}\n{% set manager_ip = salt['mine.get']('*', 'manager_ip').items() %}\n{% salt.log_message(manager_ip) %}\ninclude:\n  - docker.base\n[...]\n---"]}, u'out': u'highstate'}

Any other way to debug this?

Comment: My bad - what I meant was `{%- do salt.log.error(manager_ip) -%}` (assuming you are using salt >= 2017.7.0 https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#logs

Comment: Is there any other place I can get my logging? This is (partly) printed to my console (in logging /var/log/salt/master file i get a load of logs that aren't very readable, no new lines are used in the logging?): master.maf.cloud_master: https://gist.github.com/MaartenMol/5843d3b47892c1a25cd45d9d360267d0

Comment: I think the logs are getting polluted with errors from the `docker swarm init` not understanding the modified contents of `manager_ip`. Can you change your state file to *only* contain the `{% set manager_ip = ...%}`  and the `{%- do salt.log.error(manager_ip) -%}` logging line, and comment out the rest (`include` and `cmd.run` and see what the logs contain?

Comment: Alright, so now I am left with one logging line that says not very much? [salt.state       :320 ][ERROR   ][16207] {u'ret': {u'master.maf.cloud': {}}, u'out': u'highstate'}
(https://gist.github.com/MaartenMol/298acfe6b0d49ae859389913e0c96813)

Comment: `ret` is the value of `manager_ip` so the mine doesn't seem to be getting any data, hence why the index isn't working.

Comment: @match so I just fixed it by using another variable name: `{% set join_ip = salt['mine.get']('*', 'manager_ip').items()[0][1][0] %}

include:
 - docker.base

init cluster:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'docker swarm init --advertise-addr {{ join_ip }}'
    - require:
      - pkg: docker-ce`

When I hard coded the IP in the swarm init command I noticed that the minions (swarm workers) just joined the correct IP so they gathered the mine data correct. Copied the same salt code changed the cmd that it runs and it works fine now! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the variable name:

OLD:

```
{% set manager_ip = salt['mine.get']('*', 'manager_ip').items()[0][1][0] %}

include:
  - docker.base

init new swarm cluster:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'docker swarm init --advertise-addr {{ manager_ip }}'
    - require:
      - pkg: docker-ce
```

NEW:

```
{% set join_ip = salt['mine.get']('*', 'manager_ip').items()[0][1][0] %}

include:
 - docker.base

init cluster:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'docker swarm init --advertise-addr {{ join_ip }}'
    - require:
      - pkg: docker-ce
```